# What conditional syntax does aura/lightning support?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, expressions

Does lightning only support conditional functions provided in this [document](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_functions.htm)?

Or can I use javscript conditional format?

Example:

```
<aura:if isTrue="{!or(!v.displayTodayOnly, and(lessthanorequal(v.beginningOfDay, registrant.startTime), lessthanorequal(registrant.startTime, v.endOfDay)))}" >
```

vs

```
<aura:if isTrue="{! !v.displayTodayOnly || (v.beginningOfDay <= registrant.startTime && registrant.startTime <= v.endOfDay)}" >
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Expression Operators Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_operators.htm) illustrates that you can use operators like `<=` (actually has to be `&lt;=`) and `!` and `||`. The implementation is unlikely to be the execution of the raw JavaScript so best stick to the documented operators and syntax only.

(I don't see `(` and `)` mentioned but they do appear in examples.)

See [aura/aura-components/src/test/components/expressionTest/functions/functions.cmp](https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura/blob/4105c834179352b6ab5b6157f079122b28a85a52/aura-components/src/test/components/expressionTest/functions/functions.cmp) for some example expressions that use entities like `&amp;` and `&lt;`.

Comment: hmmm tried doing this but am getting an error
`Message: The value of attribute "isTrue" associated with an element type "aura:if" must not contain the '<' character.`

Comment: @Programatic Yeah you would have to use the entity `&lt;=` that isn't very readable.

Comment: Thanks for documenting this stuff. I'd say Salesforce's documentation on this is rather misleading.

Comment: @Programatic I've run into this too; to be fair about the documentation, the page I linked to says "escape the <= operator to &lt;= to use it in component markup".